# sqlAlchemy with multiple relationship and files

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Helo everyone,

We are currently working with SQLAclchemy and Flask on a web service. As part of this work we have a class A in file A.py:

```
from common import db

class A(db.Model):
    ...
    b = relationship('B')
    c = relationship('C')
    ...
```

B and C are located in two distinct files (b.py and c.py).
The current eanpoint we create needs only A and B classes, but we are forced to include C:

```
from common.a import A
from common.b import B
from common.c import C

class NewResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # do something with A and A.b
```

If I remove the import of C I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to
>   initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.
>   Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|A|c'. Original exception was: When
>   initializing mapper Mapper|A|c, expression 'C' failed to locate a name
>   ("name 'C' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding
>   this relationship() to the  class after both
>   dependent classes have been defined.

We are also looking at the whole idea of seperating the class at all.

thanks for the help.